# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set parent bean factory to self at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBe

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

my error message is

```
2021-11-08 18:53:36.290[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m22512[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-11-08 18:53:36.296[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m22512[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Context initialization failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set parent bean factory to self
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.setParentBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.setParent(GenericApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:576) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:783) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

[2m2021-11-08 18:53:36.297[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m22512[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/InforConfigMig/rest]    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
```

Comment: my swagger is  below

Answer (score 0):

Add this in another configuration class, which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/docApi/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/docApi/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/docApi/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/docApi/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/docApi/swagger-ui.html**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/docApi/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Now you will be able to have access into swagger-ui.html like this:
http://localhost:8080/docApi/swagger-ui.html